# VBA to Find And Replace Blank Cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Someone closed my question, although I don't know how it could be more "focused"; it seems like a pretty straightforward and simple question:

I'm trying to write some VBA code to replace blanks cells in one column of a worksheet with the value on the same row in another column. In other words, go down all the rows and if column **D** is blank, replace it with column **A**.

I tried this but it just replaces the blank value with the contents of the top row of Column A

```
.Columns("D").Replace What:="", Replacement:=.Columns("A"), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Any suggestions?

***Thanks!***

Comment: Take a look at [`Range.SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) and `xlCellTypeBlanks`.

Comment: Or you could use a helper column, use a formula, then copy/paste as values and remove the original column with blanks?  In any case, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I think this would be better over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since your code is working, but it's just slow.

Comment: I tried this:

.Columns("D").Replace What:="", Replacement:=.Columns("A"), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

But it just replaces the blank cell in D with the value in the top row of cell A, not the value of the current row

Comment: Why did someone close my question before it was answered?

Comment: Probably because you didn't include the code you currently have, or maybe because it's a better question for Code Review.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to loop this:

```
Dim lastRow as Long
lastRow = Range("D" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i as Long
For i = 2 to lastRow ' change 2 if you want to start at any other row
    If Cells(i,4).Value = "" Then Cells(i,4).Value = Cells(i,1).Value
Next i
```